# wso2am - extending userstoremanager - Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am extending a userstore manager `ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager` for WSO2AM 2.1.0 overriding the `protected String[] doGetExternalRoleListOfUser` method to add roles from an external authorization service (roles are used for scope authorization).

All looks working locally, but in other environments (deployed on kubernetes) when requesting a token (code grant) I got [following exception](https://pastebin.com/Ft0DaM4N): Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block

(other grant types are working with no issue)

```
Error occurred while issuing the access token for Client ID : ddSiloINsMx5fwp08FqqF62hcaaa, User ID null, Scope : [] and Grant Type : authorization_code    More
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} - Error occurred while issuing the access token for Client ID : ddSiloINsMx5fwp08FqqF62hcaaa, User ID null, Scope : [] and Grant Type : authorization_code 
java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:343) 
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.ScopesIssuer.setScopes(ScopesIssuer.java:110)
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.ExtendedAuthorizationCodeGrantHandler.validateScope(ExtendedAuthorizationCodeGrantHandler.java:48)
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer.issue(AccessTokenIssuer.java:242) 
...
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.issuers.RoleBasedScopesIssuer} - Error when getting the tenant's UserStoreManager or when getting roles of user 
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:177) 
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getRoleListOfUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2586) 
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.issuers.RoleBasedScopesIssuer.getScopes(RoleBasedScopesIssuer.java:118) 
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.ScopesIssuer.setScopes(ScopesIssuer.java:109) 
...
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block
```

Checking the [source code](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.4.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/common/AbstractUserStoreManager.java) I see there are secure calls made (callSecure), which I don't see immediate reason (though I assume there must be a security reason if someone made so much effort).

The same issue pops up whe nvalidating the token (invoking an API requiring a scope)

As it is working locally, atm I am unable to provide a working testable (repeatable) case, as soon I have one I will update the question.

Using default AD userstore manager there's no issue whatsoever, just we don't have the external roles available for authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was another log entry in the wso2carbon.log (though not in the console - logs available through the carbon console)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.getLDAPRoleListOfUser(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:1928)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.doGetExternalRoleListOfUser(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:2041)
    at com.rd.poa.auth.roleuserstore.ExtRoleUserstore.doGetExternalRoleListOfUser(ExtRoleUserstore.java:162)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.doGetRoleListOfUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3730)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getRoleListOfUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2615)
```

seems users were members of groups outside the "GroupSearch" filter. Making the group search base containing all LDAP group seems to help (so far)

another needed action was stripping the `FEDERATED` realm from the username [WSO2AM2.1.0-update12 scope roles for federated users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951244/wso2am2-1-0-update12-scope-roles-for-federated-users)