# WSO2AM2.1.0-update12 scope roles for federated users

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Using WSO2AM 2.1.0-update12

- trying to get a token from an authorization code grant with role based scope:
- using SAML to authenticate users (SAML returning username only, we assume roles from the underlying AD userstore).

Complete stacktrace [is available](https://pastebin.com/VRTAvmQJ)

we have an exception:

```
DEBUG -  Found Authorization Code for Client : kf2UGHFTyCzKUNgSMc65BZNCzooa, authorized user : FEDERATED/xxxxxxx@carbon.super, scope : test001_backend 

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserRolesCache.isCaseSensitiveUsername(UserRolesCache.java:213)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserRolesCache.getRolesListOfUser(UserRolesCache.java:128)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getRoleListOfUserFromCache(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3641)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getRoleListOfUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2730)
    ... 67 more
```

thing is - in the wso2am base version 2.1.0 the authorization is working, the upgrade is needed to support application sharing between groups.

Any hint?

Edit:

the change is - user returned through SAML is assigned domain FEDERATED (so the full domain username is FEDERATED/username, which is not recognized by the userstore), using base version 2.1.0 works (I am not sure if the FEDERATED domain is set, but the user roles and scopes are validated properly)

Answer (score 0):

As a resolution - we have overwritten the method `getRoleListOfUser` on the userstore maanger stripping the realm (FEDERATED) from the username.